# image calibration manually with transformation matrices from OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, imageview, transformation, camera-calibration, calibration

I need to understand that how calibration works for cameras. I do not have basics good enough. Can someone please help me in understanding that how can I apply calibration data to an image taken with a camera for which I already have the calibration matrices such as Camera Matrix, Rotation and Translation matrix, and Distortion Matrix. I got all these using opencv, but I really do not understand how it works. Reading some tutorials helped but still not good enough. Please Please Please help me!!!!!!!!!!!
Thanks in advance,
Sumit

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to do.  You can use the calibration parameters to remove lens distortion from an image. With a single calibrated camera you can measure planar objects, or you can do 3-D reconstruction from multiple images, assuming you know the extrinsics.  With a calibrated stereo pair of cameras you can do 3-D reconstruction more easily.

I am not sure what you mean by "manually".  Generally, this is a rather broad topic, which cannot be explained in a few paragraphs. I would recommend you start with the "Learning OpenCV" book by Bradski and Kaehler.

Comment: thanks Dima. but my question is how? My Prof. asked me to do this manually but I do not get that how to proceed.